# Kinect RGB data using PyKinect directly, without pygame, to be processed using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, kinect, pykinect

I'm using pygame with Kinect sensor v1 (ofcourse in python).
Are there any methods to use data from the sensor directly for processing using opencv? (without pygame)

I tried using frame.image.bits, but it gives me a 1d array.
Is there any way I can get the frame from sensor as a frame image, so that I can use opencv to process on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from pykinect import nui
import numpy
import cv2

def video_handler_function(frame):

    video = numpy.empty((480,640,4),numpy.uint8)
    frame.image.copy_bits(video.ctypes.data)

    cv2.imshow('KINECT Video Stream', video)


#------------------------------------main------------------------------------
kinect = nui.Runtime()
kinect.video_frame_ready += video_handler_function
kinect.video_stream.open(nui.ImageStreamType.Video, 2,nui.ImageResolution.Resolution640x480,nui.ImageType.Color)

cv2.namedWindow('KINECT Video Stream', cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)

while True:

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27: break

kinect.close()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
#------------------------------------main------------------------------------
```